# How to assign classroom seating to minimize number of unique neighbors across classes

Tags: graph-theory, optimization, discrete-optimization

This question was inspired by a local school district assigning seats to try to minimize the number of students who would have to quarantine in the event of a positive COVID case.

Assume that each classroom is arranged in a rectangular grid.  If a student tests positive for COVID, the neighboring students in each class have to quarantine.  For a COVID-positive student with neighbors in every direction, this means up to 8 other students per class may be affected.

Generally speaking, the objective would be to assign students next to the same neighbors across classes, but each class may have a different grid shape (e.g., 6x5 and 7x4) or class roster.  What type of algorithm would be able to find the most optimal arrangement(s) that minimize the "worst case" - that is, minimizing the largest number of students that would need to quarantine for a single COVID case.  Note that a few seats will usually remain unoccupied, as well.

My initial thoughts were to build graphs representing the classroom layout, with seats as nodes and neighboring relationships as edges.  I wasn't sure how to proceed beyond that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use mixed integer linear programming to minimize the maximum (across all students) number of neighbors.  Let binary decision variable $x_{s,i,j,c}$ indicate whether student $s$ is assigned to seat $(i,j)$ in class $c$.  Let $N_{i,j,c}$ be the set of seats that neighbor seat $(i,j)$ in class $c$.  For $s<t$, let binary decision variable $y_{s,t}$ indicate whether students $s$ and $t$ are neighbors in some class. Let $z$ represent the maximum number of neighbors.  The problem is to minimize $z$ subject to linear constraints:
\begin{align}
\sum_{i,j} x_{s,i,j,c} &= 1 &&\text{for all $s$ and $c$} \tag1\\
\sum_s x_{s,i,j,c} &\le 1 &&\text{for all $(i,j)$ and $c$} \tag2\\
x_{s,i,j,c} + x_{t,i',j',c} - 1 &\le y_{s,t} &&\text{for all $s<t,c,i,j,(i',j')\in N_{i,j,c}$} \tag3\\
\sum_{t>s} y_{s,t} + \sum_{t<s} y_{t,s} &\le z &&\text{for all $s$} \tag4\\
\end{align}
Constraint $(1)$ assigns each student to exactly one seat per class.
Constraint $(2)$ assigns at most one student to each seat per class.
Constraint $(3)$ forces students $s$ and $t$ to be neighbors if they are assigned to neighboring seats in class $c$.
Constraint $(4)$ enforces the minimax objective.

---

For your example data, here's an optimal seating assignment with objective value $4$:

```
Class 1:
 8  4  6 10 
14  3  . 12 
 2  5 15  1 
13  9 11  7 

Class 2:
18 16 17  . 23 
24  .  . 20 19 
 . 25  . 22 21 

Class 3:
 1 15  3  5 
21 11  .  9 
19  7  . 13 
23 17 25  . 

Class 4:
16  6  4 12 10 
14  8  .  . 24 
 2  . 18 20 22
```

Because class $1$ has only one empty seat, some student in class $1$ must have four neighbors, so $4$ is clearly a lower bound, even without calling a solver.  The seating assignment shown above achieves that lower bound.

Comment: Thanks for the formulation!  Just to make sure I understand, does (1) require that every seat in a class have a student?  If I want the option to have empty seats, that would just change to <= 1?  Also, does the inequality in (2) allow a student to not be a member of a class?  I would just need to keep track of which students are on the roster of each of class to make sure that every student in a class is assigned a seat in that class.

Comment: No, (1) requires that every student in a class has a seat.  And (2) already allows empty seats because of $\le 1$.  If student $s$ is not in class $c$, then just omit all such decision variables that involve that pair $(s,c)$.  Do you have actual data for this that you can share?

Comment: I don't have any real data, but I can construct an example. Let there be 25 students and two classrooms. c1 is arranged as a 4x4, and c2 as a 3x5. For the first half of the day, c1 has students 1-15, and c2 has 16-25.  In the second half, c1 has odd numbered students while c2 has even numbered.

Comment: I updated my answer to show an optimal solution for your example data.